# Extracting View tables and columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to know all the tables and columns that are used in a view so that I can create a new view with some customization. This customization involves replacing table names and columns.

I know I can get the view definition using

```
SELECT definition FROM pg_views WHERE viewname=view_name;
```

But that only gives me a string that I can use to replace values.

And the code below only lists the view column names not the original columns. And it can't list tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
AND table_name   = 'my_view'
```

Is there a way to get list of tables and columns in a view?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using SQLAlchemy, so I couldn't use commandline qgsql

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to find *original* columns, other than parsing a view definition. Postgres doesn't store this kind of relations. You can find dependencies only on table level.

Answer (score 0):

all tables in views:

```
select t.tablename from pg_tables t
where (SELECT 1 FROM pg_views v where position((' ' || t.tablename || ' ') in v.definition) > 0 limit 1) = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. The code you have shared gives all the tables, I guess used by all views. However, what I want is, to list all tables in a specific view and possibly the columns also.